# GCP CloudBuild reach Nexus(repository management) node in VPC

Tags: google-cloud-build

I have build and nexus(repository management) running in the same project.  But my CloudBuild job is not able to reach nexus node in VPC. Do I need to provision public IP to my nexus node or there is way to reach nexus node sort VPC peering between CloudBuild and my VPC?

Answer (score 0):

Per further research it seems it is not possible which will require to expose Nexus to public.  But if reverse flow this can be used: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access